# Can see out of stock products even though out-of-stock products set to NOT show?

Tags: stock

As the title says, I have set the out-of-stock products to not display when we run out of stock, but despite clearing cache, I can still see out-of-stock products visible on the site, even though it clearly says in the listing that we are out of stock.

Any ideas?

Sure it's a simple one.

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting to the products?  Direct links will always work by default, the option to not display out of stock products is supposed to hide them from searches and category listings.

Comment: Have you tried reindexing as well?

Answer (score 3):

In admin panel go to

**System > Configuration >Catalog > Inventory**

There you can have the option to show out of stock products option in frontend (yes/no).

Just make it no and it will resolve your issue  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, but I already did this and it hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: did you run index management.That also some time shows issue..Please  check and let me know